# Installing Python Libraries in Built-from-source Python 2.7.11

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have built python from scratch and it now sits in a folder in my home directory. I am unsure of how to install libraries for this particular version/location.

Ubuntu comes with 2.7.6 and I need something in particular from 2.7.11.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "built from scratch" I think "rewrote the entire python base" which is very unlikely to be what you did, could you elaborate on what you mean by "built from scratch"

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen what terminology would you use to concisely say downloaded source, fulfilled dependencies and did a make? Would built-from-source be better?

Comment: built from source would have prevented my confusion but I really just wanted to make sure I understood that you were referring to building it from the source code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get setuptools

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get install python-setuptools
 apt-get install python-pip
```

If you plan to use git and other tools install

```
 apt-get install git
 apt-get install python-dev
```

Once pip and setuptools are in place you can get any modules with either pip
or easy_install

Comment: Ubuntu already comes with 2.7.6, so my new python 2.7.11 is in some random directory of my choosing. How do I install packages for the python in this random directory of my choosing.

Comment: Then you get setuptools from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools (follow the instructions on this page)                                                                             and then locate ez_setup.py,  run python ez_setup.py        (you got easy_install now) and then run easy_install pip

Comment: So when you use your newly built from source python you have to provide the location of the interpreter                              /usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/bin/python -v                                                                   or create a symlink   -  for the use with virtualenv read more here http://mbless.de/blog/2016/01/09/upgrade-to-python-2711-on-ubuntu-1404-lts.html

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a conceptual step here. How will installing setup tools and pip (again) help me install packages for my custom built version of python located at ~/python2.7.11?

Comment: Once you know your Python 2.7.11 location you can run  /usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/bin/python -m pip install package_name        - verify the python 2.7.11 location first of course. This will make pip install modules for this specific version of python

Answer (score 0):

Get setuptools from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

run

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

now you got setuptools and ez_setup.py  - locate this file and run

```
python ez_setup.py
```

Now you have easy_install, so you can either use it or install pip:

```
easy_install pip
```

At that point you should be able to use pip.

Comment: I have pip. How do I get pip to install packages for the built-from-source version of python that resides in my ~/python2.7.11 directory instead of the system's version of python?